# Check if the app is installed inside /Application directory

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Is there a way to check if the app is installed in and launched from /Application? *My launch at login workarround only works when the app is installed inside the /Application directory.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for any app..

```
CFURLRef appURL = NULL;
OSStatus result = LSFindApplicationForInfo (kLSUnknownCreator,
                                            CFSTR("com.yourdomain.theapp"), //App bundle id.
                                            NULL,                      
                                            NULL,                      
                                            &appURL);
switch(result)
{
    case noErr:
        NSLog(@"Found my app@: %@",appURL);
        break;
    case kLSApplicationNotFoundErr:
        NSLog(@"App not found");
        break;
    default:
        NSLog(@"an error occurred: %d",result);
        break;          
}

if(appURL)
    CFRelease(appURL);
```

Answer (score 3):

you should be able to use the following command to get the path of the executable

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] executablePath]
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code should return the complete path of your executable:

```
[[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] arguments] objectAtIndex:0]
```

Then check if it falls inside /Applications